# Navigation group second window not calling third window

Tags: navigation, titanium, appcelerator

Setting up iOS navigation windows and can get first to second window to work but can't get second window to call (push on navigation stack) any other windows further.

This is working

```
window1.js
   var NewWin = require('main_windows/win2').win2();
   NewWin.containerNav = navGroup;
   navGroup.openWindow(NewWin);

win2.js
   function win2() {
      var currWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow();
      .
   return currWindow;
} // end of function win2
exports.win2 = win2;
```

But can't call win3 from win2 trying:

```
win2.js
    var NewWin = require('main_windows/win3').win3();
    NewWin.containingNav = currWindow.containingNav;
    NewWin.containingNav.open(NewWin);

win3.js

   function win2() {
       var currWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow();
       .
       return currWindow;
   } // end of function win3
   exports.win2 = win2;
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Not using Alloy?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing few things wrong here:

It should go like this:

- Create the **NavigationWindow** & hold it in a global reference as you might have already done here in **`var navGroup`**
- Use only **`var navGroup`** to open new windows, to make it global, you can either use **Alloy.Globals.navGroup** or create your **NavigationWindow** in a file which can be required as **`require('fileName');`**

  ```
  win2.js

  var NewWin = require('main_windows/win3').win3();
  navGroup.openWindow(NewWin);
  ```
- This way you do not need to attach every next window to previous window & it will become a mess when windows count will increase.
- 2nd thing you are doing wrong is calling **open** method instead of **openWindow()** in `NewWin.containingNav.open(NewWin);`